# Prevent all $state transitions until promise is resolved

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router.
I want to be able to block any state transitions until a promise is resolved.

There's are multiple states, so setting the same `resolve` property on all is not a good idea.

The promise needs to be resolved inside the Angular app, so bootstrapping the app after an external promise is resolved won't work.

My current solution relies on having a `$stateChangeStart` listener that calls `event.preventDefault();` and which removes itself after the promise is resolved. There are many complications with this solution besides the fact that its intention isn't clear unless well commented.

So, is there a better solution to block all state transitions until everything's cool?

Comment: it's generally not a good idea to block the UI. why use a promise at all if you are trying to force the app to be synchronous anyway?

Comment: It's a critical dependency without which the app cannot run. And it's not blocking the UI, per se, the thread is free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use `$urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept()`

See here: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider

```
app.config(function ($urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
};

app.run(function($urlRouter, myservice) {
  myservice.promise.then(function() {
    $urlRouter.listen();
    $urlRouter.sync();  // not sure if this is necessary
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Create one abstract parent state, make the rest children of that state. Use the resolve object on the parent state so it's resulting dependency will be available to all child states.

See: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#abstract-states

> An abstract state can have child states but can not get activated itself. An 'abstract' state is simply a state that can't be transitioned to. It is activated implicitly when one of its descendants are activated.
>
> Some examples of how you might use an abstract state are:
>
> - To provide resolved dependencies via resolve for use by child states.

Comment: I thought of that and it's not a bad idea, but I'd have to change all my states and any relative paths in the app to be children or relative to this new abstract route. ui-router has a parent overlord abstract state named `""` but I can't seem to access that as to add a resolve to it.

Comment: I know, there's work involved, you asked for the best/cleanest solution and it is in my opinion. It's not necessary to change your routing ui-sref's, state.go()'s etc as long as you don't use named parent/child states like `parentName.childName` just keep the the name of the children the same and declare the parent in the child's stateobject like: `'parent': 'parentName'`, that way `$state.go('childName')` and `ui-sref="childName"` will still work. Never noticed the overlord state you mentioned would be cool to have some sort of global resolve functionality. Too bad it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I appreciate it. To me, it's more work than just using a `$stateChangeStart` interceptor which calls `event.preventDefault()` until all promises are resolved. I was hoping there was a less artificial way of doing this altogether. Creating a state for something that should be simple seems artificial.

Comment: No thanks, you're always welcome :) If that's the case then i'de pass too if i was you. You're absolutely right, just for one resolve running an extra state is kinda ridiculous. I always make a habit of it of tacking a root state on my projects and use it for this kind of stuff plus for things like setting breadcrumbs, pagetitles, authentication and such. Always comes in handy.

Comment: That's a good point. I usually tackle such global components via state-less controllers, meaning controllers that are not tied to a state, they are always present.